# Meteor mobile responsive pages

Tags: meteor, responsive-design

I took an existing web site that was mobile responsive, turned it into a meteor application, and now it isn't responsive. Do I need to install an extension or something?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely not a meteor specific problem unless your framework requires specific loading of js to make it responsive.....

Check for your responsive framework as a package and install that. If its not there and requires JS you will need to use the compatibility folder or fix the javascript up.

There are no other features within meteor that i know of that should make "it responsive"